# Java string sorting (but not quite lexicographically)

Tags: java, string, sorting

Let's say I'm trying to sort the following array.

`String[] array = { "ABC12", "ABC1", "ABC0" "ABC9"}`

Sorting using `Arrays.sort(array)`, it becomes `{"ABC0", "ABC1", "ABC12", "ABC9"}`

However, I want to sort alphabetically by letters AND numerically by numbers appending `"ABC"` such that `array` becomes `{"ABC0", "ABC1", "ABC9", "ABC12"}`. Is there an existing method to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for an AlphaNumeric sort like [this one](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html).

Comment: Nice link although one should really fix stuff like "file05" coming AFTER "file1". Actually I think I'll mail him the trivial fix.